# PHP Loop - Check if Loop is Second item each time

Tags: php, loops, pdo

I want to add a class to an item in my loop everytime there's a looped item above it, so like this:

```
loopitem1
loopitem2 <- add class to this one
loopitem3
loopitem4 <- add class to this one
loopitem5
loopitem6 <- add class to this one
```

How can I accomplish this?

My loop looks like this:

```
while ($timeline = $fetchtimeline->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit; what I have right now;

```
            <?php
            $counter = 0;

            while ($timeline = $fetchtimeline->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $inverted = "";
                if($counter == 2) {
                    $inverted = 'class="timeline-inverted"';
                    $counter = 0;
                } else {
                    $counter++;
                }
                ?>
    <li <?php echo $inverted; ?>>
      <div class="timeline-badge primary"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></div>
      <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-heading">
          <h4 class="timeline-title"><?php echo $timeline['title']; ?></h4>
          <p><small class="text-muted"><?php echo $engine->readable($timeline['timestamp']); ?> by <?php echo $engine->pullName($timeline['postedby']); ?></small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-body">
          <p><?php echo $timeline['content']; ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: You mean every other row or can you be more specific? `modulus operator` comes to mind

Comment: modulo http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: @chris85 ah, you edited. *naughty naughty* lol

Comment: @chris85 Yes, every other row. Odd and even loops.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Haha i never spell it right, always have to google it.

Comment: @chris85 modulus/modulo, same animal just of different colors ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say, use [the modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).  Specifically for your example code:

```
$i = 0;
while ($timeline = $fetchtimeline->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $i++;
    if ($i % 2 === 0) {
        // add your class here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a counter to track how many loops you're on and make sure you reset it with every successful 2nd loop.

```
$counter = 0;
while ($timeline = $fetchtimeline->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  if ($counter == 2) {
     do_stuff_here
     $counter = 0;
  }
  else {
     $counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I've updated the question with the code I have right now

Answer (score 0):

you can use the modulus of a number

```
<?php

$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

foreach ($array as $a) {
    if ( $a % 2 == 0 ) {
        echo $a;
    }
}
```